# cakephp displaying data on specific conditions

Tags: cakephp

I've created a relationship request page, now the issue I have is when I make a relationship active it continues to be displayed in the view. I only want the requests with the field active =false displayed.

here is my request controller, it crashes due to the arrays, how can I get around this?

```
public function request(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Relationships');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';
        $userid = $this->Auth->user('username');
        $this->set('Relationships', $this->Relationship->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Relationship.partytwo' => $userid)) array('conditions'=>array('Relationship.active'=false))));

    }
```

for giggles, here is my view

```
<?php foreach($Relationships as $relationship):?>
                    <tr> 

                        <td align='center'><?php echo $relationship['Relationship']['partyone']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $relationship['Relationship']['partytwo']; ?></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($relationship['Relationship']['partyone'], array('action'=>'approve', $relationship['Relationship']['id'])); ;?>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the set statement:

```
$this->set('Relationships', $this->Relationship->find('all', 
  array('conditions' => array(
    'Relationship.partytwo' => $userid,
    'Relationship.active' => false)
  )
));
```